# Java: Time drift

Tags: java, datetime, scheduling

I've got a class that acts as Clock from a time in the past, that can be played back at different speeds.  In my example code below I am playing back at 60x.

I'm noticing that the time drifts by a second or so every 10 seconds, and I'm wondering how to deal with it.

```
import java.util.Calendar;

public class Clock {

    long delta;
    long lastCalledTime;
    long startingTime;
    private float speed = 1f;

    public synchronized long getAdjustedTimeMillis() {
        long time = (System.currentTimeMillis() - (delta));
        long val = (startingTime + (long) ((time - lastCalledTime) * speed));
        return val;
    }

    public synchronized void setPlaybackSpeedFromTime(float speed, long startingTime) {
        this.startingTime = startingTime;
        this.delta = System.currentTimeMillis() - startingTime;
        this.speed = speed;
        this.lastCalledTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - delta;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.set(2010, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4);
        Clock clock = new Clock();
        clock.setPlaybackSpeedFromTime(60f, calendar.getTimeInMillis());
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
            calendar.setTimeInMillis(clock.getAdjustedTimeMillis());
            System.out.println(calendar.getTime());
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }


    }

}
```

Here is the output I'm getting:

```
Tue May 04 04:04:04 PDT 2010
Tue May 04 04:05:06 PDT 2010
Tue May 04 04:06:06 PDT 2010
Tue May 04 04:07:06 PDT 2010
Tue May 04 04:08:06 PDT 2010
Tue May 04 04:09:06 PDT 2010
Tue May 04 04:10:06 PDT 2010
Tue May 04 04:11:06 PDT 2010
Tue May 04 04:12:06 PDT 2010
Tue May 04 04:13:07 PDT 2010
Tue May 04 04:14:07 PDT 2010
Tue May 04 04:15:07 PDT 2010
Tue May 04 04:16:07 PDT 2010
Tue May 04 04:17:07 PDT 2010
Tue May 04 04:18:07 PDT 2010
Tue May 04 04:19:07 PDT 2010
Tue May 04 04:20:07 PDT 2010
Tue May 04 04:21:07 PDT 2010
Tue May 04 04:22:07 PDT 2010
Tue May 04 04:23:08 PDT 2010
Tue May 04 04:24:08 PDT 2010
```

As you can see the "seconds" drifts.  What I want is this:

```
Tue May 04 04:04:04 PDT 2010
Tue May 04 04:05:04 PDT 2010
Tue May 04 04:06:04 PDT 2010
Tue May 04 04:07:04 PDT 2010
Tue May 04 04:08:04 PDT 2010
Tue May 04 04:09:04 PDT 2010
Tue May 04 04:10:04 PDT 2010
Tue May 04 04:11:04 PDT 2010
Tue May 04 04:12:04 PDT 2010
Tue May 04 04:13:04 PDT 2010
Tue May 04 04:14:04 PDT 2010
Tue May 04 04:15:04 PDT 2010
Tue May 04 04:16:04 PDT 2010
Tue May 04 04:17:04 PDT 2010
Tue May 04 04:18:04 PDT 2010
Tue May 04 04:19:04 PDT 2010
Tue May 04 04:20:04 PDT 2010
Tue May 04 04:21:04 PDT 2010
Tue May 04 04:22:04 PDT 2010
Tue May 04 04:23:04 PDT 2010
Tue May 04 04:24:04 PDT 2010
```

Comment: Well, the problem is simple enough - Thread.sleep isn't an exact function, and also you don't take into account processing time, which will build up over many (many) iterations. Not sure how to solve it though

Answer (score 1):

Just base your time on a source you know will be accurate ... for casual applications the system clock is usually good enough.  If you try to have your app account for time, then your precision will be limited by the concurrency robustness of your JVM.  And, honestly, this isn't the kind of thing that the JVM was intended to do well.

Comment: Indeed, Java was built for common business apps not for critical-timing applications. However, there have been attempts to build specialized [realtime Java](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_time_Java) implementations.

Answer (score 1):

you are having time drift because some time has elapsed when your process is working on other operations. instead of `Thread.sleep(int)`, try `java.util.Timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(task, date, period)`. Timer internally computes the the next execution time and triggers at the specified time. this triggering is also done internally by Timer using wait-notify locking mechanism. in short, you have to implement TimerTask that updates your Clock then use the Timer to schedule the task at the desired intervals (e.g. 1000ms).

Comment: Is this actually guaranteed to execute every 1000 ms, on the ms? Or just get something in that ballpark?

Comment: there is no guarantee and the Timer might "misfire" (miss the trigger timing). this usually occurs in an environment where there are large no. of threads and the thread pool is small. for the usual cases, the timing is very accurate.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use the system clock directly?

```
initialStartTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
while (true){
    if (intialStartTime - System.currentTimeMillis() % 1000 == 0){
        System.out.println(calendar.getTime());
    }
}
```

Obviously, you'll want to run the above on a background thread, and instead of while(true) have some reasonable exit condition. There's plenty of information about threads etc. on SO.